# Border between Div.span8 and Div.span3 element in twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, border

My project is using Twitter Bootstrap. It has main pane div.span8 and side pane div.span3. The entire panel have outer border to look like a box. I have added border right to main pane to make like divider between two panes. Now the problem is that the side  pane height is more than main pane, hence the border between the pane is incomplete( it is not reaching the outer border). 
The contents of both pane is dynamic.

How to resolve the issue?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the div that you have the border on to have `style="height:100%;"` then you will always have a full border.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
<div span8>
<div class="border">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: But sometime, span3 element's height is more than the height of the span8 element. In this case, the border right to span8 is improper.